# Lack of understanding infinite lists and seq operator

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

The code below retains, for a given integer n, the first n items from a list, drops the following n items, keeps the following n and so on. It works correctly for any finite list.

In order to make it usable with infinite lists, I used the 'seq' operator to force the accumulator evaluation before the recursive step as in foldl' as example.

I tested by tracing the accumulator's value and it seems that it is effectively computed as desired with finite lists.

Nevertheless, it doesn't work when applied to an infinite list. The "take" in the main function is only executed once the inner calculation is terminated, what, of course, never happens with an infinite list.

Please, can someone tell me where is my mistake?

```
main :: IO ()
main = print (take 2 (foo 2 [1..100]))

foo :: Show a => Int -> [a] -> [a]
foo l lst = inFoo keepOrNot 1 l lst []

inFoo :: Show a => (Bool -> Int -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]) -> Int -> Int -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
inFoo keepOrNot i l  [] lstOut  = lstOut
inFoo keepOrNot i l lstIn lstOut = let lstOut2 = (keepOrNot (odd i) l lstIn lstOut) in
                      stOut2 `seq` (inFoo keepOrNot (i+1) l (drop l lstIn) lstOut2)

keepOrNot :: Bool -> Int -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
keepOrNot b n lst1 lst2 = case b of
  True -> lst2 ++ (take n lst1)
  False -> lst2
```

Comment: the accumulator pattern generally can not work with infinite lists

Comment: `inFoo` returns a value only when the input list is `[]`. If the input list is infinite, no amount of `drop`ping can achieve a call to `inFoo` where the remainder of the input list is `[]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how list concatenation is implemented:

```
(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
(++) []     ys = ys
(++) (x:xs) ys = x : xs ++ ys
```

Note that

- the right hand list structure is reused as is (even if it's not been evaluated yet, so lazily)
- the left hand list structure is rewritten (copied)

This means that if you're using `++` to build up a list, you want the accumulator to be on the right hand side. (For finite lists, merely for efficiency reasons --- if the accumulator is on the left hand side, it will be repeatedly copied and this is inefficient. For infinite lists, the caller can't look at the first element of the result until it's been copied for the last time, and there won't be a last time because there's always something else to concatenate onto the right of the accumulator.)

The `True` case of `keepOrNot` has the accumulator on the left of the `++`. You need to use a different data structure.

The usual idiom in this case is to use *difference lists*. Instead of using type `[a]` for your accumulator, use `[a] -> [a]`. Your accumulator is now a function that *prepends* a list to the list it's given as input. This avoids repeated copying, and the list can be built lazily.

```
keepOrNot :: Bool -> Int -> [a] -> ([a] -> [a]) -> ([a] -> [a])
keepOrNot b n lst1 acc = case b of
  True -> acc . (take n lst1 ++)
  False -> acc
```

The initial value of the accumulator should be `id`. When you want to convert it to a conventional list, call it with `[]` (i.e., `acc []`).

---

`seq` is a red herring here. `seq` does not force the entire list. `seq` only determines whether it is of the form `[]` or `x : xs`.

---

You're learning Haskell, yes? So it would be a good idea as an exercise to modify your code to use a difference list accumulator. Possibly the use of infinite lists will burn you in a different part of your code; I don't know.

But there is a better approach to writing `foo`.

```
foo c xs = map snd . filter fst . zipWith f [0..] $ xs
  where f i x = (even (i `div` c), x)
```

Comment: Many thanks :-)
Your solution is so "beautiful" !
I'll follow your advice and put myself to difference lists ;-)

Thanks once again

Answer (score 3):

So you want to group a list into groups of `n` elements, and drop every other group. We can write this down directly:

```
import Data.List (unfoldr)

groups n xs = takeWhile (not.null) $ unfoldr (Just . splitAt n) xs

foo c xs = concatMap head . groups 2 . groups c $ xs
```

dave4420 already explained *what* is wrong with your code, but I'd like to comment on *how* you got there, IMO. Your `keepOrNot :: Bool -> Int -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]` function is *too general*. It works according to the received `Bool`, *any* `Bool`; but *you know* that you will feed it a succession of alternating `True` and `False` values. Programming with functions is like plugging a pipe into a funnel - output of one function serves as input to the next - and the funnel is too wide here, so the contact is loose.

A minimal re-write of your code along these lines could be

```
foo n lst = go lst
  where
    go lst = let (a,b) = splitAt n lst
                 (c,d) = splitAt n b
             in
                 a ++ go d
```

The contact is "tight", there's no "information leakage" here. We just do the work *twice* <sup>(*)</sup> ourselves, and "connect the pipes" explicitly, in this code, grabbing one result (`a`) and dropping the other (`c`).

--
<sup>(*)</sup> *twice*, reflecting the two Boolean values, `True` and `False`, alternating in a simple fashion *one after another*. Thus this is captured frozen in the code's structure, not hanging loose as a parameter able to accommodate an arbitrary Boolean value.

Answer (score 1):

Like dava4420 said, you shouldn't be using `(++)` to accumulate from the left. But perhaps you shouldn't be accumulating at all! In Haskell, lazyness makes straighforward "head-construction" often more efficient than the tail recursions you'd need to use in e.g. Lisp. For example:

```
foo :: Int -> [a] -> [a]     -- why would you give this a Show constraint?
foo ℓ = foo' True
  where foo' _ [] = []
        foo' keep lst
          | keep       = firstℓ ++ foo' False other
          | otherwise  =           foo' True other
         where (firstℓ, other) = splitAt ℓ lst
```

Comment: You can get rid of the `Bool` parameter to `foo'` by passing it `drop l other` in the recursive call.

Comment: True; what exactly is the benefit of this, though?